# Node.js - Scrape webpage which requires authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, web-scraping

I have a script as shown below which scans a webpage for certain text and if it's found on the page, it notifies me.

The only issue I'm currently experiencing is that to view the content on the link, it requires authentication. I have an account on the webpage, however I'm unsure how to use it with Node.js.

Here's a link to the site: http://www.roblox.com/Trade/inventoryhandler.ashx?filter=0&userid=261&page=1&itemsPerPage=14 - it will look empty, however it displays this content after logging into Roblox.com: http://prntscr.com/98u83j

Here's the current script:

```
// Import the scraping libraries
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

// Array for the user IDs which match the query
var matches = [];

// Do this for all possible users
function makeRequest(i){
    var location = "http://www.roblox.com/Trade/inventoryhandler.ashx?filter=0&userid=" + i + "&page=1&itemsPerPage=14";

    request(location, function (error, response, body) {

        console.log('request made for id '+ i);
        if (!error) {

            // Load the website content
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var bodyText = $("body").text();

            // Search the website content for bluesteel
            if (bodyText.indexOf("bluesteel") > -1) {

                console.log("Found bluesteel in inventory of user ", i);
                // Save the user ID, if bluesteel was found
                matches.push(i);
            }

        // Something goes wrong
        } else {

            console.log(error.message);
        }

        if(i==33){
            console.log("All users with bluesteel in inventory: ", matches);

            return;
        }

        makeRequest(i+1); 
    });
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me use my Roblox.com authentication (username and password) in the Node.js script.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would have to replicate their login requests, which may or may not be possible (never heard of the site). A good starting point would be watching network traffic while you login on the site with something like Developer Tools in Chrome. Then, try replicating it from something like Advanced REST Client (a Chrome extension). If it works, proceed by making the request from your code.

Comment: This sounds quite complicated as I'm new to Node.js and Javascript. Is there anyone who can help me achieve what you said?

Comment: Can I Skype you through it? It is kind of complicated.

Comment: What's your Skype, I'll add you